# How to parse the data from the json file describing via dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe, json, parsing

This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tqlKIm5leTS-ALj8w8fYtCrOqs62bNXL/view?usp=drive_link) to the [json](/questions/tagged/json) file I want to parse the data (resolve [a sentence] into its components and describe their syntactic roles.)

Form this file into a *dataframe* describing:

- keys as columns
- values in rows

Comment: I didn't check the link you shared; it would be better if you could show a sample of your data within your post, but you can achieve this using `df = pd.read_json("sample.json",l ines=True, orient='columns')`. *To deal with nested json like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768877/10452700), Furthermore you can check pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) or other related [posts](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-read-json-with-examples/)